# CakePHP make from result with set combine associative array

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, associative-array

How can I make associative array with set combine?

I have manage with merge to to make an array with index, I have just foreach troughout result and merge all 3 arrays into one, but that is not associative array, can I do it with combine?

Example :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Year] => 2003
                    [Month] => June
                    [MyCount] => 1
                )

            [MyData1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => 10
                )

            [MyData2] => Array
                (
                    [status] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Year] => 2003
                    [Month] => June
                    [MyCount] => 32
                )

            [MyData1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => 7
                )

            [MyData2] => Array
                (
                    [status] => 21
                )

        )

)
```

How can I make it to be like this :

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                ['SomeName'] => Array
                    (
                        [Year] => 2003
                        [Month] => June
                        [MyCount] => 1
                        [type] => 10
                        [status] => 1
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (

                ['SomeName'] => Array
                    (
                        [Year] => 2003
                        [Month] => June
                        [MyCount] => 32
                        [type] => 7
                        [status] => 21
                    )

            )

    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$a_final =array();
foreach($final as $data)
{
  $a_final[]['SomeName'] = array('Year' => $data[0]['year'], 
                                 'Month' => $data[0]['Month'], 
                                 'MyCount' => $data[0]['MyCount'], 
                                 'type' => $data['MyData1']['type'], 
                                 'status' => $data['MyData2']['status']);
}
```